# Custom class does not override CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble overriding CSS with styling applied to a custom class. I have applied a class to a link in the side menu. This is to change the color of text for the currently viewed page. From what I have read I need to be more specific when targetting the link but everything I have tried is not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="left_column">
    <nav class="side_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="current_side" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DIRECTIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left_column{
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 700px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5; 
}
.side_nav{
    width: 125px;  
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}
.side_nav ul, li{
    list-style: none; 
}
.side_nav ul li a{
    display: block; 
    width: 125px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: .95em; 
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right; 
    color:#666666;
}
.current_side a{
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.current_side a` means "An `a` element that is a descendant of an element that is a member of the class `current_side`.

You don't have such an element. The `a` element is a member of that class itself so to select the element you need `a.current_side`.

However, that will be a type selector + a class selector and `.side_nav ul li a` will also match the element but with the more specific **3** type selectors + a class selector, so you also need to make your selector more specific.

```
 .side_nav ul li a.current_side
```

Comment: or be lazy and use !important

Comment: Don't be lazy. `!important` will bite you later.

Comment: @vico that wouldn't solve the issue, the prob is that the anchor HAS the class currentside, it is not a child of an element with a currentside class `a.currentside` would work or `a` or `.currentside` but not `a .current side`

Answer (score 0):

You just need .current_side{} since it is the a element.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to be more specific when targeting your element:

```
.side_nav ul li a.current_side {
    color: #000000;
}
```